# Are there actually substances that can make a person not just larger but also taller?

Tags: supplements

Sometimes I see adverts on internet peddling supplements that seems to be able to make a person, not just bigger, but also taller?

Are any chemicals (whether legal or illegal) actually able to do something like that?

Comment: Only in Dr. Frankenstein's lab.  The answer is no.

Comment: Actually, testosterone in teenage years probably could. Before the growth plates in the long bones fuse. Testosterone is one of the growth anabolic hormones in the body, which is one reason why boys grow more than girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, growth hormone will help you achieve this and it is illegal without a prescription. 
This will only be effective if your bone plates have yet to fuse.